# Factory on Angular ... Is not a constructor when using it

Tags: angularjs

I have the following factory to be able to inject moment.js in my controllers:

```
angular.module("app").factory("moment", moment);

moment.$inject = ["$window"];

function moment($window) {
  return $window.moment;
}
```

Then I tried the following:

```
(function () {

  "use strict";

  angular.module("app").controller("ProjectController", ProjectController);

  ProjectController.$inject = ["projectService", "moment"];

  function ProjectListController(projectService, moment) {
     var date = new moment();
  }
}
```

But I got the error:

```
moment is not a constructor
```

If I change my factory to:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .factory('moment', function ($window) {
    return $window.moment;
  });
```

I don't get an error anymore.

What am I doing wrong with the first syntax?

Comment: I just include momentjs via script src rather than injecting it in Angular.

Comment: I have it as javascript in src ... But this is a way to use external scripts into controllers ...

Comment: I've always used it without injecting it: https://jsfiddle.net/3ajtoyfm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  angular.module('XRegExp', []).factory('XRegExp', ['$window', function ($window) {
    return $window.XRegExp;
  }]);

  angular.module('lodash', []).factory('_', ['$window', function ($window) {
    return $window._;
  }]);

  angular.module('admin', [
'XRegExp',
'lodash'
  ]);
```

now inject into your service as usual